# Does the hand-to-hand-fighting skill bonus in FTL affect the entire crew?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The description of the skill implies that a single crew member skilling up will improve the fighting-ability of your entire crew:

[image: crew skills tooltip]

“10% more **crew** damage”. Is this a typo, or is this actually how it functions?

Comment: Can also be read as: 10% more damage to opposing crew.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it doesn't mean that.

The fighting skill only affects how much damage that particular crew member deals.

In this case it can also mean that it deals 10% more damage to the enemy crew.

Comment: Does this mean it doesn't raise damage inflicted to enemy systems?

Comment: Perhaps it's worded this way to make clear that it's about hand-to-hand fighting, not ship weapons.

Comment: @Medinoc: yes, that's exactly what it means (and probably also the reason why it is worded this way). From the [wiki](https://ftl.fandom.com/wiki/Skills#Hand_to_Hand_Combat_Skill): "Combat skill only increases the damage dealt to enemy crew. It does not change how quickly they damage systems."